# trying to auto trigger StageDisplayState

Tags: flash, stagedisplaystate

I'm working with StageDisplayState for the first time.  I was wondering if there's any security reasons for not being able to trigger a FULL_SCREEN state.

In this simple class I wrote when viewed in a browser (firefox - mac), the timer event FULL_SCREEN doesn't trigger, the mouse event on the other hand does.  Any useful insight outthere?

Thanks

```
package {
import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
import flash.display.Sprite;

import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent; 

import flash.utils.Timer

public class AutoFullScreenTest extends Sprite {
    private var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,5)
    public function AutoFullScreenTest() {
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,timehandle)
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,mousehandle)
        timer.start()
    }
    private function timehandle(ev:TimerEvent):void{
        timer.stop()            
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN
    }

    private function mousehandle(ev:MouseEvent):void{
        stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN
    }       
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

According to Adobe's help for Stage.displayState...

Full-screen mode is initiated in response to a mouse click or key press by the user; the movie cannot change Stage.displayState without user input. Flash runtimes restrict keyboard input in full-screen mode. Acceptable keys include keyboard shortcuts that terminate full-screen mode and non-printing keys such as arrows, space, Shift, and Tab keys. Keyboard shortcuts that terminate full-screen mode are: Escape (Windows, Linux, and Mac), Control+W (Windows), Command+W (Mac), and Alt+F4.